# Django manytomany query weird behavior

Tags: mysql, django

I have a following models:

```
class Post(Model):
    word = TextField()
    subscribers = ManyToManyField(User, related_name='subscribed',    through='Subscription')

class Subscription(Model):
    post = ForeignKey(Post)
    subscriber = ForeignKey(User)
    date_subscribed = DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-date_subscribed', )
        unique_together = (('post', 'subscriber'))
```

What I want to do is to select all posts, order them by number of subscribers, and if the number of subscribers is equal, order by last `date_subscribed`.

My input data:

```
post1 = Post(text="post1")
post2 = Post(text="post2")
post3 = Post(text="post3")
post4 = Post(text="post4")

user1 = User(username="user1")
user2 = User(username="user2")
user3 = User(username="user3")
user4 = User(username="user4")

Subscription.objects.create(post=post1, user=user1)
Subscription.objects.create(post=post2, user=user1)
Subscription.objects.create(post=post3, user=user1)
Subscription.objects.create(post=post3, user=user2)
Subscription.objects.create(post=post3, user=user3)
Subscription.objects.create(post=post3, user=user4)
Subscription.objects.create(post=post4, user=user1)
Subscription.objects.create(post=post4, user=user2)
Subscription.objects.create(post=post4, user=user3)
```

This query works as expected but it doesn't order by `date_subscribed`:

```
Post.objects.annotate(s_count=Count('subscribers')).order_by('-s_count')
```

When I write:

```
Post.objects.annotate(s_count=Count('subscribers')).order_by('-s_count', '-subscription__date_subscribed')
```

I got weird results and I don't really understand this behavior. For above data it outputs exactly all posts with `s_count=1`.

Why `s_count` is 1? And, also how to order correctly by last `date_subscribed`?

UPD:
One more question. Why `Post.objects.annotate(s_count=Count('subscribers')).order_by‌​('-s_count', '-subscription__date_subscribed').count()` gives 4 instead of number of rows in Subscription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Subscription` is a through table for m2m relation between the `Post` and `Subscriber`, when you order on a field of `Subscription` model itself, all the posts appear as individual rows in the result set and that's why you get `s_count=1` because each post with a particular subscriber is unique.

You need to annotate the `Post` objects with the latest `date_subscribed` of all the `subscribers` and then order on annotated field:

```
posts = Post.objects.annotate(
            s_count=Count('subscribers'),
            s_date_max=Max('subscription__date_subscribed')
        ).order_by('-s_count', '-s_date_max')
```

---

**UPDATE for next question:**

If you use `count()` method it will return the number of `Posts`. You can see that it will differ from the count you get from `len(queryset.values_list('s_count', 'subscription__date_subscribed'))` because at this time the individual values for dates have been fetched in the result set.

Comment: Pretty simple. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to be of help.

Comment: One more question. Why Post.objects.annotate(s_count=Count('subscribers')).order_by('-s_count', '-subscription__date_subscribed').count() gives 4 instead of number of rows in Subscription?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I thought number of rows in Subscription model or does it count number of rows in Post model?

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand. By the way Django raises FieldError for subscribers__date_subscribed, you need subscription__date_subscribed.

Comment: Thanks. Corrected.

Comment: One more question. Together with max date, is it possible to fetch subscriber corresponding to this date?

Comment: I think that warrants a separate question on SO.