# Annotate query row with latest date and corresponding subsriber Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a following models:

```
class Post(Model):
    word = TextField()
    subscribers = ManyToManyField(User, related_name='subscribed',    through='Subscription')

class Subscription(Model):
    post = ForeignKey(Post)
    subscriber = ForeignKey(User)
    date_subscribed = DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-date_subscribed', )
        unique_together = (('post', 'subscriber'))
```

I want to annotate all posts with latest date of subscriptions and corresponding subscriber.
How to do it?

Now I have the following query (thanks to @AKS [Django manytomany query weird behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41137824/django-manytomany-query-weird-behavior/41140311)):

```
 posts = Post.objects.annotate(
            s_count=Count('subscribers'),
            s_date_max=Max('subscription__date_subscribed')
        ).order_by('-s_count', '-s_date_max')
```

Comment: So what's the problem here or what's the error?

Comment: How can I add subscriber for s_date_max?